# Windows 7 set system date/time in batch

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

I have a batch file which I need to run at a specific date in the past.  I can do this manually by changing the system date and time via the Control Panel (image below), running the batch file, and setting the date back to the current date.  However, I would like to include setting time and date within my batch file to simplify the process.  Is this possible?

[image: Date and Time Control Panel]

Comment: There's no upper limit on the amount of trouble that this can cause.  Even if there was an answer, it should not appear at a site like this because that will just get more people in limitless trouble.  This is a place for solutions, not more problems.  Voting to close.  Re-ask with the real reason you need to do this.

Comment: I disagree, @Hans. SO is for programming Q&As. And this is a valid programming question. How to change the date in a BAT file?. The answer is simple. Use `DATE`. See `HELP DATE`. You'll need to "Run as administrator". However, this might not be the best strategy for your problem, as it may have some undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATE` command can be used to set the date in Windows 7.

The following, in US-locale, all have the same effect; to set the clock to December 3, 2012:

```
DATE 12/3/2012
DATE 12-03-2012
DATE 12/03/12
DATE 12-3-12
```

Note that administrator privileges are required to perform the command.